# Why duplicate symbols persist after renaming?

Tags: objective-c, dependencies, duplicate-symbol

I have renamed in my static library some external github projects I want to distribute with my framework but while testing it with a client application adding the original source code of the dependency it still throws duplicate symbols, even that I renamed all the classes and external interfaces and implementations.

Specifically with the AFNetworking after prefixing SLKAFNetworking I get the following errors for all the classes when I add the AFNetworking and my static library in a test client.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate._manager in:
    /Users/gtas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestNewPlugin-dilozkrbnhkoxkdozyatixmngsxx/Build/Intermediates/TestNewPlugin.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestNewPlugin.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AFURLSessionManager.o
    /Users/gtas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestNewPlugin-dilozkrbnhkoxkdozyatixmngsxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTest-iOS.a(SLKAFURLSessionManager.o)
```

Any ideas? I don't quite get it.

Comment: It's the delegate `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate` declared inside AFURLSessionManager.m that is duplicated.

Comment: I guess I was too tired to notice, it was so obvious. Please answer properly to mark it. Lousy question but you never know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the delegate AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate declared inside AFURLSessionManager.m that is duplicated.